# How to add SiteCollection Administrator in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server, csom

How to add SiteCollection Administrator in SharePoint 2010 using CSOM(c#)? 'IsSiteAdmin' property is not available for SharePoint 2010.

Can I accomplish this by updating "isSiteAdmin" field value for the user in "SiteUserInfoList"? I tried below code, no exception is thrown and value remains unchanged

```
User user = web.EnsureUser(LoginName);
context.Load(user);
context.ExecuteQuery();
ListItem it = web.SiteUserInfoList.GetItemById(user.Id);
it["IsSiteAdmin"] = false;
it.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,

```
 User spUser = null;

  var spContext = SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext  (HttpContext);

  using (var clientContext = spContext.CreateUserClientContextForSPHost()) 
 { 
   if (clientContext != null) 
   { 
    spUser = clientContext.Web.EnsureUser("username@domain.com or DOMAIN\LoginName"); 
    spUser.IsSiteAdmin = true; 
    spUser.Update();

    clientContext.Load(spUser); 
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery(); 

    ViewBag.UserName = spUser.Title; 
} 
}
```

Comment: User.IsSiteAdmin property is not available for SharePoint 2010. is there any other way to do this?